# Trigger for a lot of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table that records a lot of information at any moment, for example, 100 rows per second.

After completing each row, certain operations must be performed. That is, some of these rows should be copied to another table.

Now a few questions:

1. Can I use triggers to do this? Given the high number of entry rows
2. If multiple conditions are checked for copying to the table, can the triggers be responsive?

Additional explanation: the records added to this table are added by the fingerprint recorder

Comment: How does this rows inserted?

Comment: Yes, you can use triggers for this.  Yes it will affect performance.  You will have to size your hardware accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, check these :

1.refer to define your trigger it can be called in insert or update etc. which not need to be executed for all operations(not required for all inserts)

2.you can forget your business during the times by changing some rules of your application

3. you need to pay attention to it for every change (prevent to introduce bugs)

4....

I strongly suggest you do not define trigger unless you have not any other choices.

if you have an application, you can do it in that and with putting the business 
(for Instance, make a thread in your application to check and do your business)

you can have a windows service to do that for you

if you have just database access you can define a job in that to do it for you (not recommended)

finally, to avoiding blocks if you decided to use multi-thread(second thread according to your question is just for read data from your original table and insert into another), you can turn on the is_read_committed_snapshot_on in your database